# Setting Up Git Remote

Tags: git

In the past I usually worked on small projects that didn't require large/growing teams, but now my current project has reached maturity and is worked on by several people regularly, making it necessary to set up version control. I set up Subversion in the past, and used git, but never set up git from scratch.

So I might be asking the wrong questions (please bear with me and point to the right questions if so), but basically what I want is a repository (on a server running CentOS and cPanel/WHM) to which the developers can push their changes from remote computers (running any OS), but at the same time it would work as a production-like environment which can be thoroughly tested/actually used through the browser (it's a web app) and it's not too much of a hassle to copy it to a real production environment. It seems like a simple proposition to me, but I encountered a surprising amount of difficulty with this setup.

So I read a large number of tutorials, and the two most relevant are these:

- http://tecadmin.net/git-tutorial/git-create-remote-repository/
- http://orange-coding.net/2012/08/24/creating-a-git-remote-repository-on-your-server/

They both describe essentially the same process. There are a number of things I don't understand however:

1. If I create a bare repository in the folder where the actual code goes, it turns it into a total dump, making it more difficult to work with overall, and definitely much more difficult to copy to a real production environment. Gone is the elegant `.git` folder. Is this necessary? Can it be avoided?
2. Remote connection has never actually worked for me (tried from the Windows git app, both through UI and command line). This is not surprising considering there is no credential system set up. How is this set up, and what else do I need to know for remote connections, especially from Windows? Like for the git URL, do I have to use something like `ssh://git@[IP]/path/to/repo` (even if I have an alias)? **Edit:** I found a way to authenticate with SSH keys in the git docs, but this method is not only very Windows-unfriendly, but it will also be difficult to test and explain for various IDE integration with git etc. I will try it myself but would still like to know about other options (username/password-based basically) if possible. Issue #3 is also related to this problem.
3. This goes back to both 1 and 2: both tutorials mention that I need to set up a dedicated user that has ownership/permissions for the git repository. This is an antithesis to how cPanel/WHM works. Is this avoidable through authentication (to git) with the cPanel user that will own the files under normal cPanel operation?